# Jasper iReport 3.0.0 font missing after reinstall the font

Tags: java, jasper-reports

It used to work perfectly fine until I reinstalled a font.
It doesn't show up anymore and I can't find any solution in their community.

I'm using win10 with jre1.8.0_171.

Can anybody help?
Thank you in advance.

It's the one in the red box :

[image: It's the one in the red box.]

Answer (score 0):

Closed. 
You need to put the fonts into your java runtime's fonts folder.